# Красноречивее и красноречивей

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте, в каких случаях используется слово "красноречивее" и в каких "красноречивей"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантные формы с суффиксами-ее и-ей (глупее – глупей ) различаются в употреблении. Форма с суффиксом-ей употребляется преимущественно в разговорной речи, а также в поэзии: "Стала забывчивей всех забывчивых. Тихо плывут года" (А.Ахм.).
http://www.konspektov.net/question/477003
Так что в устном разговоре уместно"красноречивей", а в письменной речи -"красноречивее"

Answer (score 2):

Есть у Пушкина вопрос,
Он легендами оброс:
"Кто на свете всех милее,
Всех румяней и белее?"

Не вопрос, а просто смех - 
Наша Дуня лучше всех!
И уже так много дней
Всех румяней и белей!

Answer (score 0):

Я пока точно не знаю эту тему хорошо, но могу сказать, что разница лишь в стилистике. Посему Вы можете использовать оба варианта, причем во всех прилагательных в сравнительной степени.